# How to cleanly capture from an infinite generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, generator

I feel like there should be a cute way to make the following (non-working) code work:

```
a, b, c, d = generator()
```

where the generator is infinite and the objects produced are somehow interesting. This is just intended to be a nice way of saying, make all of these variables distinct (maybe) things from this generated pattern. Unfortunately it's a syntax error.  We could do this:

```
a, b, c, d, *_ = generator()
```

But unfortunately this tries to make `_` into an infinite list, which is not what I want. I was hoping it would just grab the remnants of the generator (for future reference or just to ignore).

I could also do something like this:

```
gen = generator()
a, b, c, d = (gen.__next__() for _ in range(0, 4))
```

but this requires me to specify the 4, which I would prefer not to do. The itertools islice notation looks nicer:

```
a, b, c, d = itertools.islice(generator(), 4)
```

but still has the same problem of needing to count. Not the end of the world, I know, but it feels like this should be a solvable problem!

Comment: No, unpacking sequence requires same element count for LHS and RHS. It cannot deduce it implicitly.  `islice` is a way to go.

Comment: `globals().update(zip('abcd', gen()))` might work for you,`zip` trims up `gen` accordingly. You'd still need to specify the `'abcd'` part.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard that would also require my variable names to be one character, right? Although I guess I could do ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

Comment: @RichardRast yup, if they contain multiple characters a list is better, I opted for `'abcd'` for conciseness.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard solution is very neat, but I feel specifying the interval is a small price to pay to be explicit

Answer (score 1):

A verbose approach based on thinking of the infinite generator as being a stream that can fill a pool as needed, from which items can be taken. Error handling can fill the pool when an assignment tries to take too much.

```
import itertools

poolSize = 1000

#example stream:
def generator():
    i = 1
    while True:
        yield i**2
        i+=1

def fill(pool,gen):
    pool += itertools.islice(gen, poolSize - len(pool))

gen = generator()

pool = []
fill(pool,gen)

try:
    a,b,c,d,*pool = pool
except ValueError:
    fill(pool,gen)
    a,b,c,d,*pool = pool
```

Having done this, I don't think it is worth the hassle. How hard is it to count the number of variables on the left hand side of an `islice`?

Comment: I'm struggling to see what this does that `a, b, c, d, *not_wanted = islice(gen(), 1000)` wouldn't do anyway? You're not keeping re-filling to meet demand etc... and there's a lot of code... (and btw - catch `ValueError` in this case instead of a blanket except)

Comment: I agree that this is a lot of extra code, and probably not worth the trouble. Plus it either allocates a lot of excess objects or throws a lot of errors (depending on the pool size). When writing the question, I was hoping there was a way to get around the autolisting from (e.g.) `a, b, *_ = gen()`.

Comment: The idea is that there is no reason to assume that `not_wanted` is in fact not wanted, subsequent assignments (perhaps in a loop) should be from `not_wanted` (or `pool` in my code) rather than fresh calls to `islice()`, but then you are left with the problem that without counting (which OP wants to avoid) you don't know if the pool is large enough to fill the next request, hence the error trapping. You are right that using `ValueError` is more accurate. I'll fix that.

Comment: @RichardRast I agree that it isn't worth the hassle. I was just trying to see (as proof-of-concept) if there is a way to make something like `a,b,c,d,*rest = gen` work with an infinite stream. There doesn't seem to be an elegant way to do so.